# (MVVM) View Model per View or per Model?

Tags: ios, design-patterns, mvvm

:)

I’ve watched and read lots of MVVM materials during the past few weeks and there seems to be a major difference which everybody does in one way or another but doesn’t elaborate upon. Do we create a ViewModel per View or per Model?

There’s a question for it, but I don’t think its [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9413654/11432255) thoroughly. So..

Let’s use a Recipes app for example where we have three different views: RecipesViewController, RecipeViewController and RecipeCell. I think that the correct way to implement MVVM is to create one ViewModel per view instead of creating a RecipeModel and sharing it across them.

This example may be basic enough and we may prefer one ViewModel, but it’s not correct, is it? And if both are acceptable, can someone explain the differences, drawbacks & benefits? And if we have a networking layer, only the ViewModel should communicate with it, right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Patterns and architectures can be hard to understand when people do think in the *correct* way to do implement them.

They are just guidelines. They give you separation of responsibilities and you as a developer decide how to apply them based on your problem. Doing them one way can be harder then doing them the other way and that's pretty much it.

There is not way for a pattern to solve all the problems that you going to have.

From practice people have found out that in most cases its better for a `View` to communicate with a single `ViewModel`. My experience has proven that this indeed makes your logic cleaner as a change in couple of `ViewModel` can break a single `View` and debugging and tracing what is happening can be harder. If you do need to share some state and/or logic between `Views` that belongs to a single `ViewModel` think think how you can have two `ViewModels` instead of one and add a `Model` to share that state and logic and have `ViewModels` share that object.

A `ViewModel` can communicate with multiple `Views` (while every View has a single ViewModel). Most of the time if you can make a single `ViewModel` to communicate with a single `View` them do it. It makes things easier.

For complex interrelated logic sometimes having a single `ViewModel` per `View` can be harder to do. Usually you will divide your `ViewModel` in hierarchy where you will have one `ParentViewModel` and couple of smaller finer grained `ChildViewModels`. But these `ChildViewModels` may have to communicate with their parent or between each other. By breaking `ViewModels` into hierarchies you can achieve the single `ViewModel` for View, but if you can't don't force yourself. Sometimes it's simpler to not do it.

At least don't start by trying to have a single `ViewModel` for `View`. Use iterative approach and refactoring. Make one larger `ViewModel` and hook it to different `Views`. Later refactor your way towards breaking the `MainViewModel` into smaller ones and trying to make them communicate with less views possible.

Sharing one `Model` between `ViewModels` is perfectly fine. I think that `Models` are probably the thing that is underused. People do try to add more logic to the `ViewModels` creating coupling between them while they should use `Models` instead.

One important thing you need to think about is the division of ***Presentation*** and ***Model***. Work more on your ***Model*** and you will see great benefits.

If your example you should have a `Recipe` model as `Recipe` is your [DomainModel](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) and should have data and behavior related to a recipe. Then you will have a `RecipeViewModel` and is part of your ***Presentation*** and has the presentations logic for a `Recipe`. Then you will have your `RecipeView` that will be hooked to a `RecipeViewModel` that has the responsibility of having the actual GUI widgets that represent how a `Recipe` is ***Presented*** to the user and react and adjust it's widgets/controls to changes in `RecipeViewModel`.

In MVVM, `Views` usually don't communicate with `Models`. They do communicate with `ViewModels` that then communicate with `Models`.

One big issue that I see is that people treat `Models` as the thing that they store to the database and everything else (`Views`, `ViewModels`, `Services` etc.) as the application. That is a big flaw. If you haven't read [Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) I highly recommend it as it explains in great details the value of having good `Models`.

Here are some resources:

- https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html
- https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html
- https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PresentationDomainDataLayering.html
- [Developing GUI Applications. Architectural Patterns Revisited](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-610/paper11.pdf)
- http://aspiringcraftsman.com/2007/08/25/interactive-application-architecture/